# Python List Reverse Function

Tags: python, list

Python Novice. Need to create a list which is a reverse of the previous list. Ran the follow code:

```
list_10 = [1,10,20,4,40,14]
list_11 = list_10.reverse()
print (list_11)
```

I get an output that says "None"

Any suggestions?

Comment: `reverse()` reverses in place. It doesn't return anything. Use `list_11 = list(reversed(list_10))`

Comment: @MarkMeyer note, `reversed` returns an iterator

Comment: You can also use slice `list_11 = list_10[-1::-1]` to make a copy of the original list in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `reverse()` reverses the list in place, it returns none.

Try this.

```
list_10 = [1,10,20,4,40,14]
list_10.reverse()
list_11 = list_10
```

Comment: the op likely wants to create *a new list*